# How could I write a Latex tag in source form in section name?

Tags: listings, tex-core, verbatim

I tried to use `\verb||` and `\lstinline[language={[LaTeX]TeX}]{}` and they failed.
I just want to write a name of latex tags in section names for internal purposes.
For example, I couldn't compile a document with next line:

`\subsection{\lstinline[language={[LaTeX]TeX}]{\dot}}`

Comment: Can you just use `\texttt`?

Comment: @AndrewCashner, that solved my problem, thanks.
Example is here:
`\subsection{ \texttt{\textbackslash{dot}} and \texttt{\textbackslash{cdot}} }`

Comment: @AndrewCashner -- `\textbackslash` gives a "text" backslash, not one in the monospace font.  ``\char`\\`` does give the "tt" backslash.

Comment: use ``\texttt{\char`\\xxx}`` to enter a command name entirely using the "tt" font.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the pointer. How did you write that control sequence inline in your comment? For me it comes out as `\char`\\`.

Comment: @AndrewCashner -- how to write: two backticks, \char, one backtick, two backslashes, <whatever>, two backticks.  (see the [formatting sandbox](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/208/579) on meta.tex.sx for examples of this sort of thing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you only need the monospace (typewriter) font, not the other features of `\lstinline`, so you can just use `\texttt`. As @barbarabeeton points out, to get a proper backslash in the same font, use this:

```
\char`\\
```

So the command you need is this:

```
\subsection{\texttt{\char`\\dot}}
```

If you do this a lot, because it's TeX you can devise macros:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ttcode}[1]{%
    \texttt{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\ttcsname}[1]{%
    \ttcode{\char`\\#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Examples of \ttcsname{texttt}}

We are using the new commands \ttcsname{ttcode} and \ttcsname{ttcsname}.

\subsection{Use \ttcode{em} to scale with the font}

\subsection{Use \ttcsname{dot} or \ttcsname{cdot}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good, comprehensive and solid answer.